# How would I pass a JavaScript parameter into my python code in flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function reply_click(clicked_id)
      {
        document.getElementById("viewFlashcardLabel").innerHTML = '{{ flashcards.query.filter_by(id = clicked_id).first().title }}';   
      }
</script>
```

The parameter clicked_id is not being recognised by the python code in the {{ }}.
What would be an easy and secure way to fix the bug?

**Edit:**

HTML file:

```
    <script>
      function getFlashcard(id)
      {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "{{ url_for('views.get_flashcard') }}",
          data: {"id" : 1},
          success: function(){
            alert("success")
          },
          error: function(){
            alert("error")
          }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      
    </script>
```

Python file:

```
@views.route('/get_flashcard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def get_flashcard():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("recieved request")
```

The problem is that my ajax call is not being received by my python code as my test message is not being printed.

Comment: Python is running on the server and the JS will run on the client browser.

Comment: Thanks, so what would the best way to get around the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to do that with jinja template alone.

Add a new API, its url is something like `/api/get_title_by_id`. It can query the title by id parameter.

In you your javascript code, make an ajax call to the new API to get the title.

Comment: I've tried that but I am having some errors, could you check my edited post? Thanks